# Limitations of SQL Server 2012 Express version?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm aware that the SQL Server 2008 R2 Express was limited to 1 CPU and 10 GB Databases. It's not clear if Microsoft bumped those numbers up to be more reflective of 2012. I looked at several places but I still don't have a clear idea. Yes, I understand 2012 is not yet released but I have to assume it's software performance requirements are already set.

Comment: I have never really noticed all that much of a performance problem using 1 CPU.  If your database is unimportant enough to not have Maintainance plans (which Express doesn't have) then I bet your database is also not getting hit hard enough to matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I am aware there has been no official announcement of the capabilities of SQL Express 2012, although I have heard rumours that it will be the same as 2008 R2 (1 CPU and 10Gb database limit).

Microsoft have [released specifications](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/future-editions/sql2012-editions.aspx) for the standard and enterprise editions.

Comment: The limits are available now: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 11):

Now that it's been in release mode, there's more information available on [SQL Server 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/web.aspx).  It looks like you're limited to:

- 1 physical cpu (up to 4 cores)
- 1GB of memory use
- up to 10GB per database.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Answers that consist of nothing more than a link to another site are generally frowned upon - we prefer to see you incorporate the relevant information here, as Microsoft will inevitably reorganize their website and break that link one day. See [this meta topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, I understand 2012 is not yet released but I have to assume it's software performance requirements are already set.

You can't assume this - the limits of the Express Editions are not technical by nature. And as something specified by marketing, it can change any time - shortly before the product's release or even after that, where the updated code gets distributed through a service pack.

Comment: Technical or marketing, it's way more common for high level product specifications to be set ahead of product launch. (i.e. product planning)

Comment: @sid You've never been to Redmond, have you?